# python fstring with formatting

Tags: python, pandas, f-string

Would it possible to add if statement in fstrings like:

```
id1='somestring'
for row,col in <some_condition>:
    col.to_excel(f'{id1}_concat(0,row[0]))
```

where I want to pad single digit row[0] with a zero, if row[0] is anything other than single digit then no padding is applied, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to use string formatting using [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

```
ls = [1,2,10,20,3,4,30,40]

for i in ls:
    print(f'{i:02d}')
```

Output:

```
01
02
10
20
03
04
30
40
```